# Native Prolog Shell

Tags: prolog, expert-system

Recently I tried the book "Building Expert Systems in Prolog" which is freely available at http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog.

There is a code called native shell at the appendix along with a bird identification database. The problem is that after consulting with the shell and running:

main.

load.

solve.

It asks "nostrils:external_tubular?"

If you answer no, then an stack overflow occurs. The problem is probably at the section blow:

```
prove(true,_) :- !.
prove((Goal,Rest),Hist) :-
    prov(Goal,[Goal|Hist]),
    prove(Rest,Hist).
prove(Goal,Hist) :-
    prov(Goal,[Goal|Hist]).

prov(true,_) :- !.
prov(menuask(X,Y,Z),Hist) :- menuask(X,Y,Z,Hist), !.
prov(ask(X,Y),Hist) :- ask(X,Y,Hist), !.
prov(Goal,Hist) :-
    clause(Goal,Body),
    prove(Body,Hist).
```

Can somebody please please help me? Any help is highly appreciated.

Full code of the shell: http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/code/native/native.pro

Full code for database: http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/code/native/birds.nkb

I'm using swi prolog.

Comment: You are using sample code written for Amzi! Prolog with the SWI-Prolog interpreter, so my first thought is that there's some syntax incompatibility.  However the error you are reporting (stack overflow) doesn't help to pin down where there might be code that needs fixing.  Perhaps [the debugging facilities in SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=trace/0) should be your next step.  The [SWI-Prolog graphical tracer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/gtrace.html) requires the XPCE console.

Comment: The current Logtalk distribution (http://logtalk.org/) includes a port of Amzi! bird identification expert system. You can (also) browse the source code here:

http://trac.logtalk.org/browser/trunk/examples/birds

You can run the port with using most Prolog compilers (including SWI-Prolog) as the Logtalk back-end compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem to be here:

```
prove((Goal,Rest),Hist) :-
    prov(Goal,[Goal|Hist]),
    prove(Rest,Hist).
prove(Goal,Hist) :-
    prov(Goal,[Goal|Hist]).
```

Since swi-prolog allows the head ((x,y,z), [h]) to match the second prove predicate, somehow in the inference process the prove(Goal,Hist) is triggered which will cause the infinite loop to occur. It took me 8 hours to analyze the trace.

Therefore to fix the issue, we need a cut to be placed in the beginning of prove((Goal,Rest),Hist). The code should look like this:

```
prove((Goal,Rest),Hist) :-
    !,
    prov(Goal,[Goal|Hist]),
    prove(Rest,Hist).
prove(Goal,Hist) :-
    prov(Goal,[Goal|Hist]).
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem indeed manifests itself through

```
prove(Goal,Hist) :-
    prov(Goal,[Goal|Hist]).

prov(Goal,Hist) :-
    clause(Goal,Body),
    prove(Body,Hist).
```

`clause(:Head, ?Body)` should be true if `Head` can be unified with a clause head and `Body` with the corresponding clause body. Unfortunately, *for any* program SWI-Prolog believes `clause(call(X), call(X))` to be true. This means that `clause(call(nostrils(external_tubular)), X)` succeeds and `prove` is being called, which in its turn calls `prov` with ever-growing second argument.

Since `clause/2` is a static predicate, its contents cannot be modified with `retractall` or `abolish`. Possible solutions are:

1. [Report a bug to SWI developers](http://www.swi-prolog.org/bugzilla/)
2. Replace clauses in `birds.nkb` by something like `myclause` and refer to `myclause` in the implementation of the shell.
3. Look at some other Prolog dialects...

Comment: Thank you alexander for the effort. I have added the actual cause as the solution. I will award the bounty within 9 hours. I'm allowed to do it in the next 9 hours.

Comment: I think that adding `\+ Body=Goal` after `clause(Goal,Body)` should solve the `clause(call(X), call(X))` issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it by adding the predicate `prov((_,_),_) :- !, fail.` right above the section:

```
prov(true,_) :- !.
prov(menuask(X,Y,Z),Hist) :- menuask(X,Y,Z,Hist), !.
prov(ask(X,Y),Hist) :- ask(X,Y,Hist), !.
prov(Goal,Hist) :-
    clause(Goal,Body),
    prove(Body,Hist).
```